# Wordpress Multi-site Automated migaration script

Tags: deployment

Bit of a long shot but can anyone recommend a script to automate moving a Wordpress multisite from 
local to live server.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fully automated but I've used Cory Lamle's [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plug-in to move multi-site installs before.  Helpful step-by-step if you are the nervous type.

These days I just do it manually though.  After moving the files and DB I run the Interconnect/IT [script](https://www.interconnectit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/searchreplacedb21.zip) to update the URLs.

Works great but doesn't exactly answer your question for a fully automated script.